# How can I find the column index of the first non-zero value in a row with R dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working in R. I have a dataset of COVID case totals that looks like this:

| Facility | Day_1 | Day_2 | Day_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| C | 0 | 2 | 6 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I would like to use mutate() to create a new column, first_case, that has the column index of the first non-zero element in each row -- or "NA" if there is no non-zero element. I thought about using where(), but couldn't quite figure out how to get a column index instead of a row index.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to get the first instance when the value is non-zero in each zero.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(first_case = {
    tmp <- select(., starts_with('Day'))
    ifelse(rowSums(tmp) == 0, NA, max.col(tmp != 0, ties.method = 'first'))
  })

#  Facility Day_1 Day_2 Day_3 first_case
#1        A     0     0     1          3
#2        B     1     2     5          1
#3        C     0     2     6          2
#4        D     0     0     0         NA
```

`first_case` has column number of the `'Day'` columns, if you need column number in the data you can add `+ 1` to above output.

Comment: This worked perfectly and is easy to understand! Thank you, answer accepted

Answer (score 1):

This is probably unnecessarily complex, because the data is not in a long ('tidy') format that *dplyr* etc expect.

```
datlong <- dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("Day"), names_to = c("day"), names_pattern="_(\\d+)")

## A tibble: 12 x 3
#   Facility day   value
#   <chr>    <chr> <int>
# 1 A        1         0
# 2 A        2         0
# 3 A        3         1
# 4 B        1         1
# 5 B        2         2
# 6 B        3         5
# 7 C        1         0
# 8 C        2         2
# 9 C        3         6
#10 D        1         0
#11 D        2         0
#12 D        3         0
```

It's then simple to get the first/second/third/[n]th day above whatever value, as well as to calculate minimums, maximums, means, weekly averages, rolling averages, whatever, because you are now dealing with a plain old vector of values rather than a list of values across multiple columns.

```
datlong %>%
  group_by(Facility) %>%
  filter(value > 0, .preserve=TRUE) %>%
  summarise(first_day = first(day))

#`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Facility first_day
#  <chr>    <chr>    
#1 A        3        
#2 B        1        
#3 C        2        
#4 D        <NA>
```

Alternative using indexes and stuff, which is less *dplyr*-like:

```
datlong %>%
  group_by(Facility) %>%
  summarise(first_day = day[value > 0][1])
```